# Sorting and Concatenating Database SQL statements...?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know how you concatenate and sort things by ascending or descending (which is what I need help with) Here's what the questions ask:

> List the first name, last name, sales rep ID, commission class, and
>   commission rate for all Sales Reps.  Concatenate the first and last
>   names together.  Sort by last name in ascending order, and use the
>   following column headings:  SalesRep_Name, Sales_Rep_ID,
>   Commission_Class, Commission_Rate.

```
Alice Jones, Sales rep ID: 10  CommClass: A CommRate 0.1
Greg Taylor, Sales rep ID: 12 CommClass: B CommRate: .08
Sara Day,  Sales rep ID: 14 CommClass: Z CommRate: 0
Kay Price, Sales rep ID: 8  CommClass: C CommRate: .05
Alice Jones, Sales Rep ID: 10 CommClass: A CommRate 0.1
```

How do I do the concatenation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do string concatenation with SQL Server is to use `+`:

```
select 
  first_name + ' ' + last_name as SalesRep_Name,
  Sales_Rep_ID,
  CommClass as Commission_Class,
  CommRate as Commission_Rate
from your_table
order by last_name asc -- ascending is the default and doesn't need to be specified
```

Note that if either first_name or last_name is null then the result will be null, so you might want to either check for that, or use a function like `coalesce(first_name, '')` to replace the null value with an empty string.

With SQL Server versions 2012+ you can use `concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as SalesRep_Name` instead with the added bonus that `concat` handles null values too.

Comment: So would I have to put the  values for F_Name, L_name, sales_rep ID etc..? And there's no null values for the statements, they all have values. I will accept your answer, Thank you!

Comment: You obviously need to change the query to reflect what your actual column names are; it wasn't obvious from the question text. A guess would be that you should do `f_name + ' ' + l_name as SalesRep_Name` etc

Comment: You are correct F_name and L_name are set as SalesRep_Name. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS 'FullName' --concatenation
FROM yourtableName
Order by LastName ASC; -- This is sorting
```

Comment: What about the CommClass and CommRate, what do I do with those..? And do I need to add the + sign? Could I see the whole code that I way I can use it as a guide for the rest of the statements? Thanks